# HIbernate querydsl select query taking too much time

Tags: mysql, hibernate, querydsl

I have a dynamic query created by QueryDSL based on user input from UI. DB table is having around 4 million records. The entity is a simple entity with no associations or joins. It contains around 56 properties.

code:

```
@Inject
QEntityRepository qEntityRepository;
.
.
.
BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
builder.and(qEntity.firstProperty.containsIgnoreCase(firstProperty));
and so on......

qEntityRepository.findAll(builder, new PageRequest(pageable.getPageNumber(), Integer.valueOf(itemPerPage),sort));
```

Also please note that it is taking more time when I am searching with "LIKE' as shown above. But I have to search with LIKE only as per business requirement.

It is just got hanged after SQL query creation as per log. I am using Ehcache and query caching as well but of no improvement.I am using HikariCP for the pool management. DB Table is also indexed with a single index having all 4 parameters user can put on UI.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: You can do mysql testing for select, insert and update records using sysbench tools. You will get transaction per second for mysql that may be there is deadlock, read or write transaction or requests so you can trace this is mysql server issue or your application issue.